# Angular Service worker with IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Is there any way to get the IE version 11 work with service workers in an angular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No version of Internet Explorer supports service workers, not even IE11.

References:

- [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers)
- [Microsoft platform status](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/status/serviceworker/)

Comment: Thank you for responding, Crowder. Is there any alternative for service worker because I have to use Internet Explorer.

Comment: @NeerajKumarPrajapati - Not really. Depending on what you're using the service worker for, you might be able to use the now-deprecated offline application stuff (which is supported in IE10+), but there's a reason it's deprecated. :-) See the "Resources" linked from [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps).